# How would I differentiate from Click and Double Click while using a C1FlexGrid

Tags: vb.net-2010, componentone, c1flexgrid

I want to use the double click and click events for c1flexgrid in vb.net, but when I double click it only goes to the click event handler and never fires the double click event.

How can I separately handle the click and double click events?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

Pressing a mouse button when the cursor is over any particular clickable control raises the events in following order:

1. MouseDown event.
2. **Click event.**
3. MouseClick event.
4. MouseUp event.
5. MouseDown event.
6. **DoubleClick event.**
7. MouseDoubleClick event.
8. MouseUp event.

**Two single clicks that occur close enough in time**, as determined by the mouse settings of the user's operating system, will generate a MouseDoubleClick event instead of the second MouseClick event.

Therefore,

Check your mouse settings.